What does "avoid imports of package:package_name/src/" mean in the docs
In the dart documentation it says

For the best performance when developing with the development
JavaScript compiler through webdev serve, put implementation files
under /lib/src, instead of elsewhere under /lib. Also, avoid imports
of package:package_name/src/....

With the "Also, avoid imports of package:package_name/src/...." do they mean other packages? Or do they also mean avoid doing that inside your own package? So do they mean use relative imports with that? Or are they simply referring to the fact that other packages have their src folder reserved for private implementation code which should not be imported. Or both?

It means what it says.  Don't reach into the src of another package.  That name is reserved for "things without a public interface".

From https://dart.dev/tools/pub/package-layout :

You are free to import libraries that live in lib/src from within other Dart code in the same package (like other libraries in lib, scripts in bin, and tests) but you should never import from another package's lib/src directory. Those files are not part of the package's public API, and they might change in ways that could break your code.

So to directly answer your questions:

With the "Also, avoid imports of package:package_name/src/...." do they mean other packages?

Yes.  You should not depend on another package's private implementation details.

Or do they also mean avoid doing that inside your own package?

Your own package is free to use its own private implementation details however it wants.

So do they mean use relative imports with that?

Whether you want to use relative or package imports to access files in lib/src/ in your own package is unrelated.  You can do whatever you want for your own package.

Or are they simply referring to the fact that other packages have their src folder reserved for private implementation code which should not be imported. Or both?

See above.

(But do use relative paths to your own files, it makes it much easier to see on an import that they are from the same package.)

We are not using relative paths. The main thing we wanted to know is if src imports from within the package will affect web performance as well as we are compiling for web. That part is still not clear to me.

@anonymous-dev I see no reason why it would affect web performance.
